# Why Does Askubuntu Have It's Own Domain Name?

Tags: discussion

Why do some stackexchange sites such as Askubuntu have their own domain when the rest are subdomains of stackexchange.com? Why isn't it ubuntu.stackexchange.com, which currently acts as a redirect?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[At one point,](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/) all Stack Exchange sites were going to have their own domain names. This was then [rolled back](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/). There has been [some debate on the topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103470/a-plea-for-actual-domain-identities) over on Meta Stack Exchange. Ask Ubuntu was both grandfathered in and part of an agreement between Stack Exchange and Canonical. [This answer by Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103686/151585) gets to the point:

> Any way, long story short -- if you can get Apple, Inc. to officially
>   sign off on the site, we will happily change the domain name to
>   whatever is required. Beyond that Act of God scenario, we simply
>   aren't doing custom domain names for any sites as a matter of policy.

Comment: In other words, "AskApple.com" would create Trademark confusion.

Comment: @Nick Also, "AskApple.com" would make people think they were directly talking to Apple. This site is "AskUbuntu", not "AskCanonical", although I'm not 100% what "Ubuntu" means here.

Comment: @Sparhawk Ubuntu is technically a [registered trademark (see sec. 3)](http://www.ubuntu.com/intellectual-property-policy) of Canonical. It just so happens that Ubuntu is to Canonical as Windows and the Xbox are to M$. In all those cases, the product is quicker recognized than the company. More emphasis: Canonical owns www.ubuntu.com and www.canonical.com, while Microsoft owns www.xbox.com and www.microsoft.com. In both cases, the former is visited far more often.